# Create EF mapper configuration in c# for recursively nested objects in c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using visual studio 2010 .Net4.

I am having an issue trying configure a mapper to a database using EF.

Here is the class I am trying to map, I am trying to map it so that i can use an include statement to populate the list of Children based on the ParentID property of the Question object with in the list.

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    //recursive list of Questions
    public virtual List<Question> Children {get; set;}
}
```

And here is my attempt to configure the mapper

```
class QuestionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Question>
{
    public QuestionConfiguration()
        : base()
    {
        this.HasKey(x => x.QuestionId);

        this.Property(p => p.ParentId)
            .HasColumnName("ParentId");

        this.Property(p => p.QuestionText)
            .HasColumnName("QuestionText");

        this.Property(p => p.Answer)
            .HasColumnName("Answer");

        this.HasMany(w => w.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(w => w.ParentId);

        ToTable("tbl_Questions");
    }
}
```

I am still fairly new to the EF and c# so I am not really sure how to start here. My attempt above does not even compile.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close:

```
this.HasMany(w => w.Children)
    .WithOptional() // Added this
    .HasForeignKey(w => w.ParentId);
```

The only thing is, I think ParentId should be a nullable `int`, because the root of a hierarchy never has a parent.